# How to inherite modifier into multiple contracts ? Best practice?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.8.x, inheritance, modifiers

I have a project with severals contracts.

To put some security, I've created a "onlyContract" modifier on a Roles contract so some functions in diferents contracts can only be called if the contract is approved (so adding the onlyContract modifier to the function).
Users need to be able to call specific functions (without modifier) in a contract and those specific functions have  functions calls inside them to other contracts which have the "onlyContract" modifier.

Below I have created a simple example on how my implementation look like with the modifier etc...
Currently all the contracts need to be manually approved in the respective contracts (A, B, C).

Is there a better way to handle how the contracts are approved as we must use the onlyContract modifier ?
Because for now I have to call "addContract" on each contract for each contracts and it's kinda boring as I have 10 contracts.

```
contract Roles {
    mapping(address => bool) private approvedContract;

    modifier onlyContract() {
        require(approvedContract[msg.sender], "contract not approved");
        _;
    }
    function addContract(address _contractAddress) external  {
        approvedContract[_contractAddress] = true;
    }
    function removeContract(address _contractAddress) external  {
        approvedContract[_contractAddress] = false;
    }
}

contract A is Roles {
    function addition(uint256 number) public view onlyContract returns (uint256) {
        return number + 10;
    }}

contract B is Roles {
    A public a;

    function link(address _a) public  {
        a = A(_a);
    }
    function multiply() public view onlyContract returns (uint256) {
       uint256 num = a.addition(10);
       return num * 5;
    }}

contract C is Roles {
    A public a;
    B public b;
    function link(address _a, address _b) public {
        a = A(_a);
        b = B(_b);
    }
    function calculateValue(uint256 value) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 numB = b.multiply();
        return value + numB;
}}
```

Thank you for your help !